# Read binary file with Python (fwrite C output)

Tags: python, c, struct, file-io, binary

I have a big problem to read binary files generated with fwrite() function in language C and read these data with python. I can read it without problem with fread() function in C but it's impossible for me in Python.

The goal was to test binary writting in C. I write 2 same structures in a row with 2 "different" functions (just "wb" replaced by "ab"). After that i read that in the C code to check and compare with python reading.

The C code to generate and read binary file :

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
struct corsika{                                                                                                                                                                                            
  double photons;                                                                                                                                                                                          
  double position;                                                                                                                                                                                         
  double direction;                                                                                                                                                                                        
  double other;                                                                                                                                                                                            
};  

void testStruct(double * value,double * value2,double * value3, double * value4 ){                                                                                                                         
    int retVal;                                                                                                                                                                                            
    FILE *fp;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    int integer=1;                                                                                                                                                                                         
    struct corsika input;                                                                                                                                                                                  
    fp = fopen("file.txt","wb");                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    input.photons=value[0];                                                                                                                                                                                
    input.position=value2[0];                                                                                                                                                                              
    input.direction=value3[0];                                                                                                                                                                             
    input.other=(*value4);                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    fwrite(&input,sizeof(struct corsika),1,fp);                                                                                                                                                            
    fclose(fp);                                                                                                                                                                                            
}  

void testStruct2(double * value,double * value2,double * value3, double * value4, double number){                                                                                                          
    int retVal;                                                                                                                                                                                            
    FILE *fp;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    int integer=1;                                                                                                                                                                                         
    struct corsika input;                                                                                                                                                                                  
    fp = fopen("file.txt","ab");                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    input.photons=number*value[0];                                                                                                                                                                         
    input.position=number*value2[0];                                                                                                                                                                       
    input.direction=number*value3[0];                                                                                                                                                                      
    input.other=number*(*value4);                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    fwrite(&input,sizeof(struct corsika),1,fp);                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    fclose(fp);                                                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
void readStruct(){                                                                                                                                                                                        
    FILE *fp;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    int integer=1;                                                                                                                                                                                         
    struct corsika input;                                                                                                                                                                                  
    struct corsika input2;                                                                                                                                                                                 
    struct corsika input3;                                                                                                                                                                                 
    fp = fopen("file.txt","rb");                                                                                                                                                                           
    fread(&input,sizeof(struct corsika),1,fp);                                                                                                                                                             
    fread(&input2,sizeof(struct corsika),1,fp);                                                                                                                                                            
    fread(&input3,sizeof(struct corsika),1,fp);                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    printf("%f %f %f %f \n",input.photons,input.position,input.direction,input.other);                                                                                                                     
    printf("%f %f %f %f \n",input2.photons,input2.position,input2.direction,input2.other);                                                                                                                 
    printf("%f %f %f %f \n",input3.photons,input3.position,input3.direction,input3.other);                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    fclose(fp);                                                                                                                                                                                            
} 

int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    double value[4]={0.00000000002,1.00000000002,2.00000000002,3.00000000002};                                                                                                                             
    double value2=4.;                                                                                                                                                                                      
    double value3[4]={5.00000000002,6.00000000002,7.00000000002,8.00000000002};                                                                                                                            
    double value4[4]={9.00000000002,10.00000000002,11.00000000002,12.00000000002};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    testStruct(value,value3,value4,&value2);                                                                                                                                                               
    testStruct2(value,value3,value4,&value2,2.);                                                                                                                                                           
    testStruct2(value,value3,value4,&value2,4.);                                                                                                                                                           
    testStruct2(value,value3,value4,&value2,8.);                                                                                                                                                           
    testStruct2(value,value3,value4,&value2,16.);                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    readStruct();                                                                                                                                                                                         
    printf("\n");                                                                                                                                                                                          
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

The Python Code to read the output file  :

```
import struct

fileC7_photons  = open("file.txt","rb")
s = struct.Struct("<dddd")
record = fileC7_photons.read(32)
print (s.unpack(record))
```

The output in C code :

```
0.000000 5.000000 9.000000 4.000000 
0.000000 10.000000 18.000000 8.000000 
0.000000 20.000000 36.000000 16.000000
```

The output in the python reader for the 4st values :

```
(6.9528567926909e-310, 6.9528567926925e-310, 6.95285679269407e-310, 6.9528567926905e-310)
```

What is wrong in my procedure ? I tried to change "<" by ">" for the python struct but it doesn't work too.

Hexdump results :

```
0000000    6495    e179    fd7f    3db5    57f6    0000    0000    4014
0000010    2bfb    0000    0000    4022    0000    0000    0000    4010
0000020    6495    e179    fd7f    3dc5    57f6    0000    0000    4024
0000030    2bfb    0000    0000    4032    0000    0000    0000    4020
0000040    6495    e179    fd7f    3dd5    57f6    0000    0000    4034
0000050    2bfb    0000    0000    4042    0000    0000    0000    4030
0000060    6495    e179    fd7f    3de5    57f6    0000    0000    4044
0000070    2bfb    0000    0000    4052    0000    0000    0000    4040
0000080    6495    e179    fd7f    3df5    57f6    0000    0000    4054
0000090    2bfb    0000    0000    4062    0000    0000    0000    4050
00000a0
```

Thank you

edit : I changed pointers in the structure

edit2 : I simplified the problem and changed values between lines to be sure I have good values at the end. It works now. Thank you !

Comment: `fwrite(input,sizeof(struct corsika),4,fp);` - open the file in a hex dump and just look at what is actually written. You're writing four structures, each of which have nothing more than *pointers* as members. the value of the pointers is what is being written; nothing more. And FYI, this would equally fail dreadfully if your reader and writer were in two different processes. The only reason it seems to "work" (term used loosely) in C is because your test reader is the same process as your writer, and the memory used for the latter inconveniently wires to the former.

Comment: Should `struct corsika` hold doubles instead of pointers to doubles? You don't seem to have any policy for these pointers. Do they point to single doubles or perhaps a list of doubles? Who owns the memory and how do you handle freeing the memory?

Comment: Ok I removed the pointers. I checked outputs and it's ok now with the C reader and added the hexdump result. But it doesn't work on python.

Comment: `In function ‘testStruct’: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double’ from type ‘double *’ |       input[i].photons=&value[i];`

Comment: Besides, the amount of trailing white space is ridiculous.

Comment: Sorry for the bad copy paste. I forgot to remove "&" characters here. If you want to remove blanks, it's simple. You can remove spaces. It's just a test, not an example about a precise and beautiful writting.

Comment: Your C and Python code now work as is for me (`(2e-11, 5.00000000002, 9.00000000002, 4.0)`) and your hex dump agrees with mine.  What compiler/OS are you using?  Make sure you aren't running the Python code on an older iteration.

Comment: Ok it's fine, I didn't use the last binary file :D thank you